# I want to create a complete copy of the form on add more button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamic

I have a simple question although i new how to generate a textbox on button click event but what i am looking for just like on linkedIn when you are adding education and experience there is add more button which open a complete section for adding new education so user can add any many education as he want i want to do the same in asp.net mvc also is there any example which shows that functionality i want to save all these records into their rows in table using model binding not using javascript.

I want to create a complete dynamic form on button click just like linkedIn do add more education add more experience

no code

it should create the same form as many times as i click the button and then save all those records to db using .net mvc with model binder

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var counter = 2;
    $("#addButton").click(function () {  
 if(counter>10){
      alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
      return false;
 }   
  
 var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
      .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
                
 newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
       '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + 
       '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');
            
 newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup"); 
 counter++;
     });
     
     
  $("#removeButton").click(function () {
 if(counter==1){
          alert("No more textbox to remove");
          return false;
       }   
        
 counter--;
     $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();
     });
  
     $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {
  
 var msg = '';
 for(i=1; i<counter; i++){
      msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
 }
       alert(msg);
     });
  });
</script>
</head><body>

<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
 <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
  <label>Textbox #1 : </label><input type='textbox' id='textbox1' >
 </div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
<input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'>
<input type='button' value='Get TextBox Value' id='getButtonValue'>
```

Comment: is there any way to completely create all elements all nodes inside that div rather than manually adding all elements because in my case i have 5-8 controls with labels and validator and CSS i want all to be copied .